# is it possible for Cougars and Cheetahs to reproduce

Tags: zoology

I know that many big cat hybrids exist ie ligers, but I always thought it these hybrids were limited to members of the Panthera genus till I came across a cross between a leopard and a cougar. Now since cougars and cheetahs are more closely related to each other than to leopards could these two successfully reproduce?